# Map rotation after compass clickd

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-mapview, gesture-recognition

I have a map API V2 fragment.
And have enabled compass.
After two fingers rotation of the map, the compass can be clicked to reset map rotation.
How can I figure out the angle of rotation after compass clicked?

Comment: Can you vote up the answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GoogleMap#getCameraPosition().bearing`

Answer (score 0):

Use Sensor to get angle of Rotation

```
private float[] mapGravity;
private float[] mapMagnetic;

private float getmapDirection()
{

    float[] maptemp = new float[9];
    float[] mapR = new float[9];
    //Load rotation matrix into mapR
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(temp, null,
            mapGravity, mapMagnetic);


    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(map_temp,
            SensorManager.AXIS_X,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Z, mapR);

    //Return the orientation values
    float[] values = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(mapR, values);

    //Converting  to degrees
    for (int i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        Double degrees = (values[i] * 180) / Math.PI;
        values[i] = degrees.floatValue();
    }

    return values[0];

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch(event.sensor.getType()) {

    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        mapGravity = event.values.clone();
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        mapMagnetic = event.values.clone();
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
    if(mapGravity != null && mapMagnetic != null) {
        getDirection();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I use the sensor to get rotation when I'm rotating the phone. But when compass is pressed it dose not use sensor, it rotates the map.